# Get maximum from two tables sql

Tags: sql, max

I am making an electronic voting website and have two tables on for vote and the other for candidates I want to get the maximum number of votes for each candidate and I need to produce the result for each candiate like:
candidate name: number of votes

My tables looks like:

```
candidate:Id,name
vote:Id,candidateID,numberofvote
```

and here is my query

```
SELECT Vote.Id, 
 Vote.NumberOfvote, 
 Vote.CandidateID, 
 Candidate.Name 
FROM Vote 
INNER JOIN Candidate 
 ON Vote.CandidateID = Candidate.Id
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Is `Vote.NumberOfVote` a field? Or do you want to `Count(Vote.NumberOfVote)`? It's confusing how your `Vote` table is setup. And I don't think you want the `MAX()` votes, just a `Count()` of votes for each `Candidate`.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understood what is you problem, but anyway you need to use Max() and GROUP BY. something like this:

```
 SELECT Candidate.Name, Max(Vote.NumberOfvote) 
 FROM Vote INNER JOIN Candidate 
 ON Vote.CandidateID = Candidate.Id 
 GROUP BY Candidate.Name
```